# Laravel eloquent -- Field name returning null from trait

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Here is what I'm trying to do..

I have a `enquiries` table where job enquiries are stored. This stores a start address, and a finish address. Also stores `predictive_price` which is set to null when an enquiry is added.

The `predictive_price` is calculated dynamically and once the enquiry has been confirmed, the `predictive_price` is then stored within the table. This is because that during an enquiry lifetime, it could change addresses, distances or the tariffs that are set. I do not want to keep updating the `predictive_price` in the table everytime something has changed, it just allows for errors.

This is what I've done so far:

Inside my model `Enquiries` I have a function:

```
public function predictive_price() {
    return $this::calculatePredictivePrice();
}
```

This is then calling a method inside a `trait` where my model references such `use EnquiriesHelper;`

Inside the `EnqEnquiriesHelper` I have the following:

```
public function scopeCalculatePredictivePrice()
{
   return 1;
}
```

But when trying to output `predictive_price` is just says `null` which is what is stored within the database. Is there anyway (using methods) I can override what is being returned in `predictive_price`?

Answer (score 0):

$this::calculatePredictivePrice() to $this->calculatePredictivePrice() maybe ?

## UPDATE

It shouldn't be a scope.Try removing the scope before the functions name

Comment: Nope! Still returning `null` `$this->calculatePredictivePrice()` will just do the same thing as what's there now

Comment: I didn't see it before, but It shouldn't be a scope.Try removing the scope before the functions name

Comment: No, this has not worked either. I mean, is it even possible?]